# Determining Python Class' Type with Inherited Classes

Tags: python, oop

I have multiple class that all inherit from a single base class, and here is a simple example:

```
class DataSource(object):
    pass
class TableDataSource(DataSource):
    pass
```

If I want to determine if these classes are of type DataSource, I figured I could do the following:

```
>>> tdl = TableDataSource()
>>> print tdl is DataSource
False
```

So I get back false here, how can I check if all my class that inherit from DataSource are datasource type objects without having to check for each class type specifically?  It would make checking for object types easier for other functions down the road.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The things about `is` is that it's testing to if the two objects reference the same thing. `DataSource` the class is an object. Hence, only something referencing `DataSource` itself would compare true. What you should use is `isinstance` like this:

```
  isinstance(x, DataSource)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `isinstance`:

```
>>> tdl = TableDataSource()
>>> isinstance(tdl, DataSource)
True
```

For classes use `issubclass`:

```
>>> issubclass(TableDataSource, DataSource)
True
```

Comment: This answer worked as well, thank you as well, but someone beat you to the point first!

Comment: @josh1234 Shockingly the timestamps are exactly the same. :)